# WordPress - any good Forum options?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, forum

Is there any good forum plugin out there for WP 3.0 ?
I've checked out [WP Forum](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpforum/) but it's full of bugs... bbpress also pretty much sucks, very hard to integrate with wp and is missing a lot of stuff that a generic forum has...

Comment: There is a wordpress StackExchange site you should ask this on.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I greatly hesitate to say this, but SimplePress integrates with WordPress. However, it kinda sucks.

There are a couple people working on forum plugins which use WordPress' Custom Post Types. [Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/16/a-wordpress-forum-plugin-using-custom-post-types) and [the bbPress team](http://bbdevel.wordpress.com/) are working on forum plugins. Doesn't really help too much in the short term though.

Edit: Justin says his plugin [will be released soon.](http://popcritics.com/forums/topics/very-nice-cant-wait-for-the-plugin#post-10227)

Comment: yea simplepress sucks...
justin's forum looks good, I'm really curious how it will turn out :D
I guess I'll wait

Comment: I neglected to mention BuddyPress as an option. It has a built-in, already integrated instance of bbPress. I'm not sure if you'd be able to disable everything else to strip it down to just the forum though.

Answer (score 2):

You should give [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) a shot.  It's not a plug-in like WP Forum, but a standalone forum implementation that runs on a similar codebase.  The beauty of the system is that it's developed by the same core group, so updates/support won't go anywhere.

For a live example, check out the [official WordPress support forums](http://wordpress.org/support) ... they run on bbPress.

Answer (score 1):

I am the lead developer for [WordPress Forum Plugin](http://www.wordpressforumplugin.com), a fully featured forum plugin for WordPress blogs.  I was equally frustrated with the forum plugins available to WordPress administrators and decided to work on a solution.  It utilizes MyBB as the base forum package but integrates seamlessly with WordPress.

We aren't quite release-ready but are looking for beta testers if you are interested.  More information can be found at our site.